# Correct Asset URL when using folders

Tags: assets, url

My Craft blog has the path `localhost:8888/blog`
The Assets are in the folder assets, so its `localhost:8888/blog/assets`.
I set the path of an image to `/assets`, but then it looks for an image at `localhost:8888/assets`. Is there any way to handle this dynamically, without needing to write blog/ in front of every asset url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also found this slightly confusing from time to time. These settings work well for me:

FYI, on the server the path is: **.../public_html/uploads/services**

Hope it helps

[image]